# Component development, how to update submenu in administration?

Tags: component, php

I added in my helper file new sub-menu item, also in xml file like every other sub-menu item, but there is still not visible in administration, i tried wit discover functionality but this is not the solution, how can i do it? Every other sub-menu items are already visible.

PHP Definition is like every other:

```
   JHtmlSidebar::addEntry(
        JText::_('COM_BTICKETS_TITLE'),
        'index.php?option=com_btickets&view=btickets',
        $vName == 'btickets'
    );
```

XML Definition also like every other:

```
<menu link="option=com_btickets&amp;view=btickets" view="btickets" img="components/com_quickhshop/assets/images/s_pricess.png" alt="Btickets/Tickets">COM_BTICKETS_TITLE</menu>
```

View names, xml & php definitions are 100% true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reinstall your component with the updated XML definition. The PHP definition is just for the menu on the left side in the backend and does not update your database with the new sub menu item.